# Что нужно для FillContainsWithDetail

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите пожалуйста что делать в такой ситуации, сначала я делаю :

```
var g = tb.RenderedGeometry;
g.Transform = (Transform)tb.TransformToAncestor(actualcanvas);
var m = ta.RenderedGeometry;
m.Transform = (Transform)ta.TransformToAncestor(actualcanvas);
IntersectionDetail khg = m.FillContainsWithDetail(g);
```

... для двух rectangle и всё отлично срабатывает, потом я серелизую(json) два rectangle и повторяю этот же код, но нечего не срабатывает, мне кажется что это какой-то параметр не хочет сериализоваться и я вот думаю может этот мне неизвестный параметр отдельно сериализовать? Так вот спросить я хотел какой мне параметр сериализовать, чтобы можно было делать `FillContainsWithDetail`?

Comment: Я ж говорил, не стоит сериализовать UI-объекты.

Comment: Ну блин, так переделывать не охота, так как долго (уже программа готова, только вот сохранение осталось сделать) и сложно это на mvvw и тяжко из-за отсутствия отладки в патерне